# Change the telegram code, so that the letter A is added to the beginning of each message

Tags: android, telegram, message

I compile my own android version, and I can't find where could insert anything before user message for example letter "A". Anybody know where I could find part where sending text forming?

I looked through files, and from what i see message text transfering from bytes, so i must write my letter like const in bytes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I need in SendMessagesHelper.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).